# How to convert async call into sync?

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm pretty new to RxJava and I would like to make a method call, that returns an Observable, sync.

This is the method signature:

```
JsonObject login();
```

I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
public JsonObject login() {
    return eventBus
    .sendObservable(...)
    .toBlocking().first().body();
}
```

How can I make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: What specifically does not work (any error you getting)? Also you mentioned that you need to call login() but the code sample has eventBus.sendObservable() call. What does it return?

Answer (score 0):

Observable by design is Synchronous, if you want any operation Asynchronous you must use one of the specific operators.(onSubscribe, onObserver, buffer....)

Also don't use toBlocking unless for your test, is almost an anti pattern, try to use the Observer pattern instead.

```
     public void main(String args[]){

         login().subscribe(jsonObject-> do Whatever you need);
     }


     public Observable<JsonObject> login() {
        return eventBus.sendObservable(...) --> I guess this call return an Observable
     }
```

If you want to take a look some basic examples take a look here https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Comment: I don't completely understand this... you must use 'subscribe()' in order to make the login() call work. otherwise it never return ...(I think they call it "cold observable")...

Comment: Yes, it´s call it "cold" since when you create your observable is lazy, so no execution is made until you subscribe an observer, moment when the observable become eager and the execution start